# Delete all records under KV v2 in Hashicorp using API HTTP request

Tags: list, kivy-language, delete-operator, hashicorp-vault, hashicorp

I wish to delete all records under kv (versioned) using API [HTTP request]. Using CLI is a secondary preference.

Upon my research, I found that there is no way to delete all entries under `kv` in one go.

Instead we should first `LIST` and then delete all records in a loop.

Below is my attempt on Listing all entries under the kv.

Display path for `kv`:

```
C:\Users\meuser>curl -H "X-Vault-Token: s.XTEZVwE5WOill0as1HXV6w2Z" -H "X-Vault-Namespace: devops-vault-poc/"  https://dal-vault.mybank.com/v1/sys/mounts

{"request_id":"93fdc050-d5d1-fbe2-df58-2a2bba04f19c","lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":0,"data":{"cubbyhole/":{"accessor":"ns_cubbyhole_12e4f0fa","config":{"default_lease_ttl":0,"force_no_cache":false,"max_lease_ttl":0},"description":"per-token private secret storage","external_entropy_access":false,"local":true,"options":null,"seal_wrap":false,"type":"ns_cubbyhole","uuid":"b9276a30-73c0-5d2f-34c0-238b5830c572"},"identity/":{"accessor":"ns_identity_50d4ced6","config":{"default_lease_ttl":0,"force_no_cache":false,"max_lease_ttl":0},"description":"identity store","external_entropy_access":false,"local":false,"options":null,"seal_wrap":false,"type":"ns_identity","uuid":"8b5b546f-33d6-1234-6f38-9ddcde05c55d"},"kv/":{"accessor":"kv_b93d663b","config":{"default_lease_ttl":0,"force_no_cache":false,"max_lease_ttl":0},"description":"","external_entropy_access":false,"local":false,"options":{"version":"2"},"seal_wrap":false,"type":"kv","uuid":"42834004-f858-a734-e52d-6405d0e5ab73"},"sys/":{"accessor":"ns_system_573b63e0","config":{"default_lease_ttl":0,"force_no_cache":false,"max_lease_ttl":0},"description":"system endpoints used for control, policy and debugging","external_entropy_access":false,"local":false,"options":null,"seal_wrap":false,"type":"ns_system","uuid":"bfce2504-fff5-b74f-70a0-0b2fe3fb500d"}},"wrap_info":null,"warnings":null,"auth":null}
```

[image]

Attempt 1 to List entries:

```
C:\Users\meuser>curl -H "X-Vault-Token: s.XTEZVwE5WOill0as1HXV6w2Z" -H "X-Vault-Namespace: devops-vault-poc/" -X LIST https://dal-vault.mybank.com/v1/kv

{"request_id":"884ad3f2-80c3-fb99-d5c9-83f059f41319","lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":0,"data":null,"wrap_info":null,"warnings":["Invalid path for a versioned K/V secrets engine. See the API docs for the appropriate API endpoints to use. If using the Vault CLI, use 'vault kv list' for this operation."],"auth":null}
```

Attempt 2:

```
C:\Users\meuser>curl -H "X-Vault-Token: s.XTEZVwE5WOill0as1HXV6w2Z" -H "X-Vault-Namespace: devops-vault-poc/" -X LIST https://dal-vault.mybank.com/v1/kv/

{"request_id":"c898ffc6-7ac8-faa6-87aa-e8f57045c6d3","lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":0,"data":null,"wrap_info":null,"warnings":["Invalid path for a versioned K/V secrets engine. See the API docs for the appropriate API endpoints to use. If using the Vault CLI, use 'vault kv list' for this operation."],"auth":null}
```

Attempt 3:

```
C:\Users\meuser>curl -H "X-Vault-Token: s.XTEZVwE5WOill0as1HXV6w2Z" -H "X-Vault-Namespace: devops-vault-poc/" -X LIST https://dal-vault.mybank.com/v1/kv/data/

{"errors":["1 error occurred:\n\t* unsupported operation\n\n"]}
```

Comment: You could also re-create the secret engine mount to delete all records. Would that be an ok solution?

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard I would like to know that solution but I'm not sure how to. However, API  to list and delete all key-value is my preference?

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/api-docs/secret/kv/kv-v2#list-secrets), to perform a LIST operation you need to use the `/metadata/` paths. So the appropriate command for you would be

```
curl -H "X-Vault-Token: <token>" -H "X-Vault-Namespace: devops-vault-poc/" -X LIST https://dal-vault.mybank.com/v1/kv/metadata/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete every secret, disable the mount and enable it again. It will mount a fresh new and empty copy.

Let's enable it and and put some secrets in it:

```
$ vault secrets enable --path kv --version 2 kv
$ vault kv put kv/hello a=42
$ vault kv put kv/world b=42
```

You'll have two secrets, `hello` and `world`:

```
$ vault kv list kv
Keys
----
hello
world
```

Now disable the mount :

```
$ vault secrets disable kv
Success! Disabled the secrets engine (if it existed) at: kv/
```

Enable it again, see that it is empty:

```
$ vault secrets enable --path kv --version 2 kv
Success! Enabled the kv secrets engine at: kv/
~
$ vault kv list kv
No value found at kv/metadata
```